# Embaressingly parallel processing using Open MPI and OpenMP

Tags: openmp, openmpi

It may be a silly question, anyway I am working on an embarrassingly parallel problem. I can divide the work into independent tasks (no communication) that can be performed in parallel.

In a shell `script.sh` one can use the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
let MY_ID=${OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK}
./a.out $MY_ID
```

In `prog.c` we have a simple independent program:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int myid = atoi(argv[1]);
  if(myid%2==0)
    printf("\nI am %d and I am an even process\n", myid);
  else
    printf("\nI am %d and I am an odd process\n", myid);
  return 0;
}
```

And finally, to execute the program with 12 different processors:

```sh
mpirun -np 12 script.sh
```

My question is that is it possible to do the same thing using OpenMP and perhaps environment variables like `OMP_NUM_THREADS` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OpenMP environment variable which, when passed to a program in the way you indicate, will be given a value different for each invocation of the program.  If you think about how OpenMP works you might think, as I do, that this doesn't make much sense - since the OpenMP program is implemented as a collection of threads.  This is in marked contrast to the model of operations of MPI in which each process is a separate process, bolstered with a library for inter-process communications - in this case it makes sense that each process have a unique identifier for facilitating communication.  When an OpenMP program executes communication between threads is effected by operations on shared memory locations, not by passing messages to specified threads.

In passing, you're not really writing an MPI program, just using one of the facilities its environment provides for making your shell-script writing a little easier.  You could almost as easily write a shell-script to send a different id to each invocation of the program without the MPI environment - and you could do the same for invocations of an OpenMP program.  Though why you would do either if your programs really are independent I don't know.

Comment: "You could almost as easily write a shell-script to send a different id to each invocation of the program without the MPI environment - and you could do the same for invocations of an OpenMP program", is my post the idea that you have?

Comment: No.  I fail to understand why you are 'using' either MPI or OpenMP.  For an embarrassingly parallel problem, one in which each 'task' is entirely independent of every other task, neither is needed and both impose unnecessary complications in code construction.  OpenMP will probably impose an unnecessary run-time overhead too.

Comment: Maybe I could not explain clearly, A bash script simply can run a program and change a parameter for each run by a recursive loop, but recursively means you can use one core and other cores are idle. I use MPI or OpenMP to have e.g 4 recursive loops and in each loop and each core, an independent task is running.

Answer (score -1):

Too long to post it as a comment. Actually, this kind of parallel processing is useful for ensemble modeling. When your program runs for different initial condition, and each run creates different folder or output file.

I came up to this :

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
g++ prog.cpp -fopenmp
./a.out
```

in `prog.cpp` we have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<string>

using std::string;

int main(){
    int nthreads, tid;
    string cmd;

    #pragma omp parallel private(tid)
    {    
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        cmd = "echo 'this is a test. I am thread :' " + std::to_string(tid) ;
        system(cmd.c_str());  //each thread can creat a folder and run a script  
        // system("./my_script.sh");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the output as follows:

```
this is a test. I am thread : 0
this is a test. I am thread : 3
this is a test. I am thread : 2
this is a test. I am thread : 1
```

Comment: `cmd` is shared in your example, so you have a huge race condition.

Comment: @Zulan: thumb up.